# JPQL queries refering columns defined via UserType

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpql, usertype

I have defined a **custom user type** for for a business class , using **two columns**.

I am not able to refer to it in **JPQL queries**.

```
  class Entity {
      [...] 
  @Columns(columns = { //
  @Column(name = "col1"), //
      @Column(name = "col2"), //
  })
  public MyClass getMyObject() {
    return object;
  }
     [...]
  }
```

How should I refer to it in a JPQL query ?

```
  select e from Entity e where e.col1 = ?1 and e.col2 = ?2
```

JPA does not seems to know about those columns.

Comment: If it turns out, no existent solution: try adding two not-insertable and not-updatable JAVA fields mapped to those DB columns and use them in your query.

Comment: You mean some private getter/setters that do nothing ?

Comment: Something like that (it depends whether you mapped the JAVA fields or the getters)